# Any way to get user input from a hook?

Tags: pre-commit.com

I have this ruby code in a hook, but it does not hang to wait for user input as I would like.

```
puts 'Do you really want to commit on master? [y/N]'

answer = gets.strip
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`git` hooks are not handed a tty so doing something like this is tricky

additionally the framework is designed to *never* have interactivity.  you can hack it together by hijacking `/dev/tty` -- though this is not portable and not recommended.

the suggested approach instead if you want some explicit user input is to produce an error suggesting the user utilize [`SKIP=hookid`](https://pre-commit.com/#temporarily-disabling-hooks) for the next run

for more on this, there are a few duplicates in the issue tracker:

- [pre-commit/pre-commit#871](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/871)
- [pre-commit/pre-commit#872](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/872)
- (also check the linked issues there)

---

disclaimer: I am the author of pre-commit